# Qt 5 with MSVC and NMake doesn't work

Tags: c++, windows, qt, nmake, msvcrt

When I compile a **fresh** Qt project with the new Qt Creator 2.6.1 and Qt 5.0 I get the following errors:

```
C:\Qt\Qt5.0.0\Tools\QtCreator\bin\jom.exe -f Makefile.Debug
Error: cannot open C:\Users\Ömercan\AppData\Local\Temp\main.obj.7320.31.jom for write
jom: C:\Projekte\PixelGame\src\com\pearstudios\texturepacker\TexturePacker-Debug\Makefile [debug] Error 1
19:46:21: The process "C:\Qt\Qt5.0.0\Tools\QtCreator\bin\jom.exe" terminated with exit code 2.
Error while building/deploying project TexturePacker (kit: Desktop Qt 5.0.0 MSVC2010 32bit (SDK))
When executing step 'Make'
```

After changing the options to use NMake directly I am getting the following errors:

```
"C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\bin\nmake.exe" -f Makefile.Debug
    cl -c -nologo -Zm200 -Zc:wchar_t -Zi -MDd -GR -W3 -w34100 -w34189 -EHsc -DUNICODE -DWIN32 -DQT_WIDGETS_LIB -DQT_GUI_LIB -DQT_CORE_LIB -DQT_OPENGL_ES_2 -DQT_OPENGL_ES_2_ANGLE -I"..\..\..\..\..\..\..\Qt\Qt5.0.0\5.0.0\msvc2010\include" -I"..\..\..\..\..\..\..\Qt\Qt5.0.0\5.0.0\msvc2010\include\QtWidgets" -I"..\..\..\..\..\..\..\Qt\Qt5.0.0\5.0.0\msvc2010\include\QtGui" -I"..\..\..\..\..\..\..\Qt\Qt5.0.0\5.0.0\msvc2010\include\QtCore" -I"debug" -I"." -I"." -I"..\..\..\..\..\..\..\Qt\Qt5.0.0\5.0.0\msvc2010\mkspecs\win32-msvc2010" -Fodebug\ @C:\Users\Ömercan\AppData\Local\Temp\nm25A.tmp
NMAKE : fatal error U1077: ""C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\bin\cl.EXE"": Exit-Code "0xc0000135"
Stop.
NMAKE : fatal error U1077: ""C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\bin\nmake.exe"": Exit-Code "0x2"
Stop.
19:49:49: The process "C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\bin\nmake.exe" terminated with exit code 2.
Error while building/deploying project TexturePacker (kit: Desktop Qt 5.0.0 MSVC2010 32bit (SDK))
When executing step 'Make'
```

When changing the TEMP and TMP environment variable to another path with full ascii characters (so not using the non-ascii character 'Ö') I get the following errors with JOM:

```
C:\Qt\Qt5.0.0\Tools\QtCreator\bin\jom.exe -f Makefile.Debug
    cl -c -nologo -Zm200 -Zc:wchar_t -Zi -MDd -GR -W3 -w34100 -w34189 -EHsc -DUNICODE -DWIN32 -DQT_WIDGETS_LIB -DQT_GUI_LIB -DQT_CORE_LIB -DQT_OPENGL_ES_2 -DQT_OPENGL_ES_2_ANGLE -I"..\..\..\..\..\..\..\Qt\Qt5.0.0\5.0.0\msvc2010\include" -I"..\..\..\..\..\..\..\Qt\Qt5.0.0\5.0.0\msvc2010\include\QtWidgets" -I"..\..\..\..\..\..\..\Qt\Qt5.0.0\5.0.0\msvc2010\include\QtGui" -I"..\..\..\..\..\..\..\Qt\Qt5.0.0\5.0.0\msvc2010\include\QtCore" -I"debug" -I"." -I"." -I"..\..\..\..\..\..\..\Qt\Qt5.0.0\5.0.0\msvc2010\mkspecs\win32-msvc2010" -Fodebug\ @C:\Projekte\TMP\main.obj.764.31.jom
jom: C:\Projekte\PixelGame\src\com\pearstudios\texturepacker\TexturePacker-Debug\Makefile.Debug [debug\main.obj] Error 2
    cl -c -nologo -Zm200 -Zc:wchar_t -Zi -MDd -GR -W3 -w34100 -w34189 -EHsc -DUNICODE -DWIN32 -DQT_WIDGETS_LIB -DQT_GUI_LIB -DQT_CORE_LIB -DQT_OPENGL_ES_2 -DQT_OPENGL_ES_2_ANGLE -I"..\..\..\..\..\..\..\Qt\Qt5.0.0\5.0.0\msvc2010\include" -I"..\..\..\..\..\..\..\Qt\Qt5.0.0\5.0.0\msvc2010\include\QtWidgets" -I"..\..\..\..\..\..\..\Qt\Qt5.0.0\5.0.0\msvc2010\include\QtGui" -I"..\..\..\..\..\..\..\Qt\Qt5.0.0\5.0.0\msvc2010\include\QtCore" -I"debug" -I"." -I"." -I"..\..\..\..\..\..\..\Qt\Qt5.0.0\5.0.0\msvc2010\mkspecs\win32-msvc2010" -Fodebug\ @C:\Projekte\TMP\mainwindow.obj.764.31.jom
jom: C:\Projekte\PixelGame\src\com\pearstudios\texturepacker\TexturePacker-Debug\Makefile.Debug [debug\mainwindow.obj] Error 2
jom: C:\Projekte\PixelGame\src\com\pearstudios\texturepacker\TexturePacker-Debug\Makefile [debug] Error 2
19:53:52: The process "C:\Qt\Qt5.0.0\Tools\QtCreator\bin\jom.exe" terminated with exit code 2.
Error while building/deploying project TexturePacker (kit: Desktop Qt 5.0.0 MSVC2010 32bit (SDK))
When executing step 'Make'
```

And with NMAKE:

```
"C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\bin\nmake.exe" -f Makefile.Debug
    cl -c -nologo -Zm200 -Zc:wchar_t -Zi -MDd -GR -W3 -w34100 -w34189 -EHsc -DUNICODE -DWIN32 -DQT_WIDGETS_LIB -DQT_GUI_LIB -DQT_CORE_LIB -DQT_OPENGL_ES_2 -DQT_OPENGL_ES_2_ANGLE -I"..\..\..\..\..\..\..\Qt\Qt5.0.0\5.0.0\msvc2010\include" -I"..\..\..\..\..\..\..\Qt\Qt5.0.0\5.0.0\msvc2010\include\QtWidgets" -I"..\..\..\..\..\..\..\Qt\Qt5.0.0\5.0.0\msvc2010\include\QtGui" -I"..\..\..\..\..\..\..\Qt\Qt5.0.0\5.0.0\msvc2010\include\QtCore" -I"debug" -I"." -I"." -I"..\..\..\..\..\..\..\Qt\Qt5.0.0\5.0.0\msvc2010\mkspecs\win32-msvc2010" -Fodebug\ @C:\Projekte\TMP\nm803F.tmp
NMAKE : fatal error U1077: ""C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\bin\cl.EXE"": Exit-Code "0xc0000135"
Stop.
NMAKE : fatal error U1077: ""C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\bin\nmake.exe"": Exit-Code "0x2"
Stop.
19:56:54: The process "C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\bin\nmake.exe" terminated with exit code 2.
Error while building/deploying project TexturePacker (kit: Desktop Qt 5.0.0 MSVC2010 32bit (SDK))
When executing step 'Make'
```

I have not reduced the output, because there could be a problem with the command line parameters.
There is also no difference between the Debug and Release build and I also use MSVC 2010 without problems on Windows 7 32bit. I have the new MS.NET Framework 4.5 and 4 installed. Several months ago I also used the Qt Creator with Qt 4.8 without problems, but I removed it to make space for other programs. Now I need Qt again, but it is not useable, due to this problem.

Has someone an idea? Something I could try?

Comment: There might be a problem with the missing mspdb100.dll. I don't know why he is missing, but I will reinstall the whole MSVC and .NET environment. Hope it will work :/

Comment: Still same error, also after trying a whole new deinstall of the .NET SDK and Visual Studio. Now I use Visual Studio 2012 and I already compiled Qt 5 successfully with MSVC 11. So no problems in the MSVC environment. :/

Comment: After trying and trying I decided to use Java, like the other parts, again. Poorly noone wrote an answer, but maybe someone will post an possible answer sometime. So this question is still actual, but not so important anymore for me.

Comment: You should really ask for support in the Qt channels, not on StackOverflow.

Comment: Yeah, true. Why not thought about that? I will do it and post the possible answer here.

Answer (score 2):

I recently had the pleasure to find out that Qt (don't remember which version exactly) does not work when you have paths with spaces in it *sigh*. It just falls apart at some point, while other parts work. No usable error message. For that reason, I would check if it also barfs at the "Ömercan" in your path. And file a bug report, if you care.

Comment: This was also one of the reasons I thought about. But I changed the location of the project to path without spaces or non-ascii characters. Nothing changed. So this is not the reason :( But thanks for the answer :D

Comment: I just annihilated an hour learning this, don't use - or _ chars

Answer (score 2):

The Qt framework has some Paths compiled in the binaries (qmake...). When using the installer these are patched to the Tools with the Path you decided to install. You can not move your Qt installation from one directory to another. The same goes for compiling you need to compile Qt in exactly the same directory in which you want to run it. Perhaps this is the problem?

Comment: Hmm, this could be the problem. I compiled Qt in the C:/Projekte/ and used the C:/Qt/5.0/ as the configure prefix. But I compiled it with my normal account. Maybe Qt interfere with MSVC in C:/Program Files/.../VC/bin? This could be the problem. I will try it, thanks :D

Comment: After a long testing phase, I must say that this great answer is not the solution... :/ I use Java instead of Qt now, but really thanks for the answer.

Answer (score 1):

Did you compile Qt 5 yourself?

In the past, I encountered issues with Qt plugins not compiled with the right compiler flags (ex: Qt Creator built with MSVC and plugins with MinGw), DLL problems, etc.

So, when I have to work on a Qt project on Windows, I usually start by compiling Qt from source code : http://qt-project.org/wiki/Building_Qt_5_from_Git

Compilation could take a while depending on your machine processing power.

Comment: Yes I compiled Qt 5 myself, but also tried the pre-compiled binaries. Non of them worked :(